# How can I decrypt password string in PHP which was encrypted with crypt?

Tags: php, cryptography, encryption

How can I decrypt a password string in PHP which was encrypted with `crypt`?

```
$salt = substr($_POST['password'], 0, 2);  
$password = crypt($_POST['password'], $salt);
```

I need to send the original password in a *forget password* e-mail.

Comment: Password should be One Way Hashed, when the user ask for a new Password, you should send him a temporary password that he will change on next login.

Comment: I totally agree with Michael B, there's no need to revert the encryption (and it would be bad practice securitywise if it were possible), just send a new random password and have the user change it after logging in.

Comment: well there no facility for user to change his password, here only admin creates username and password and sends it to the user, Still thanks for the advise

Comment: The salt should be a random value and not be forget from the value that should be hashed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

> crypt — One-way string hashing

there is no reverse operation of crypt. The best you can - reset password and send it to user.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the answer you are looking for, but this is just a more security wise practice.

Password should be One Way Hashed, when the user ask for a new Password, you should send him a temporary random password that he will change on next login.

Answer (score 1):

1) you can use symmetric encryption instead of hash (crypt function is hash) - in this way you would have possibility to decrypt it.

2) usually sites services create *special* link and mail it to user. By this link we have page where we can change password. It is more safe way to store passwords.